# UIEvent Object vs UITouch Object

Tags: ios, uikit, uitouch

I'm not sure I understand these things, at all.

From what I can gather, a UITouch object is the container of touch information.

How does this relate to a UIEvent?

For example:

Most everyone seems to put UIEvent and UITouch handling in ViewControllers. But it seems to me that both could be dealt with in Views, too. Or even a windows. Is this right?

Where do I go to read a current, explanatory and friendly introduction to these things? The Apple docs are making my head hurt.

Comment: __briefly:__ the `UIEvent` describes that _it_ happened, `UITouch` describes that _how_ it happened; iOS handles most of the common gestures on screen via `UIEvent` (touches, motion, remotes, etc...) for you on high-level, but you don't need to stop here, you are able to catch `UITouch` on lower-level to recognise your own custom-crazy gestures, if that is the case.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get that. And that I need to declare and override one of the touch handling functions in order for something to be done with a touch (otherwise it vanishes). It seems a UITouch is an object that's "passed" to one of the handling functions, that iOS is looking out for. Those being touchesBegan(), Moved() etc.

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be somewhere that articulates "this is the sequences of processes iOS does, and this is what it's looking for, and this is how you best code to exploit this..."

Comment: And I've no idea how you'd "ask" iOS to pass you a UIEvent instead of just a UITouch.

Comment: you can't find such guide, because this topic is too generic and everyone can exploit the touch's screens capability on their own way; it is like a _screwdriwer_, you have the tool, you know what is it for, but the instruction will not show you neither a list of all types of screws nor every possible way how you can hold the tools during the procedure. that is something which you need to figure our for yourself.

Comment: you can e.g. add targets to a `UIControl` object to ask a specific (or more) `UIEvent`, which eventually interests you; you can read more about it [on __Apple's site__](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol).